# After I added some js code HTML stops noticing the .js file and returns ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on a small HTML based incremental game. A few times now when I've added some function to the game it stops working and I only get 'ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined' errors. Now if it only was the new functions that had the problem I wouldn't have much problems, but instead everything stopped working. I'm currently working localy only. 
My functions are all called on 'onClick' in HTML, however, due to the size I was unable to show both HTML and js.

JavaScript code:

```
//Base varibles

var cookies = 0;
var manualMult = 1;
var clickMult = 1;
var progMult = 1;
var accentions = 0;
var accentionMult = 1;
var accentionPoints = 0;
var accentionPointsGained = 0;



//Just calculations

function noDec(number) {
  return +(Math.floor(number));
}

function BetterRound3(number) {
    return +(Math.round(number + "e+3")  + "e-3");
}

function BetterRound5(number) {
    return +(Math.round(number + "e+5")  + "e-5");
}

var ranges = [
  { divider: 1e30 , suffix: 'e30' },
  { divider: 1e27 , suffix: 'e27' },
  { divider: 1e24 , suffix: 'Y' },
  { divider: 1e21 , suffix: 'Z' },
  { divider: 1e18 , suffix: 'E' },
  { divider: 1e15 , suffix: 'P' },
  { divider: 1e12 , suffix: 'T' },
  { divider: 1e9 , suffix: 'G' },
  { divider: 1e6 , suffix: 'M' },
  { divider: 1e3 , suffix: 'k' }
];

function preFix(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (n >= ranges[i].divider) {
      return (BetterRound3(n / ranges[i].divider)).toString() + ranges[i].suffix;
    };
  };
  return n.toString();
};

function preFix5dec(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if (n >= ranges[i].divider) {
      return (BetterRound5(n / ranges[i].divider)).toString() + ranges[i].suffix;
    };
  };
  return n.toString();
};



//Clicking

var clicks = 0;
var nextClickGoal = 5000;
var clickBonusMult = 1;

function buttonClick(number){
    cookies = cookies + number;
    clicks = clicks + number;
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(noDec(cookies)) + " Bits";
    document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = preFix(noDec(clicks)) + " Clicks";
    document.getElementById('nextClickGoal').innerHTML = preFix(nextClickGoal) + " Clicks";
    if(clicks >= nextClickGoal) {
      document.getElementById('clickCollect').innerHTML = "Click 'Bit Button' to colect bonus"
    };
    document.getElementById('clickingBonusBar').value = clicks;
    document.getElementById('clickingBonusBar').max = nextClickGoal;
};

function clickReward(){
  if(clicks >= nextClickGoal) {
    nextClickGoal = Math.floor(nextClickGoal * 14.7);
    clickBonusMult = clickBonusMult * 2;
    document.getElementById('clickBonusMult').innerHTML = "Click Bonus: " + preFix(clickBonusMult) + "x";
    document.getElementById('clickCollect').innerHTML = "";
  };
};


//Items and Multiplyers

var cursors = 0;
var cursorsBought = 0;
var nextCursorGoal = 10;
var cursorBonusMult = 1;

function buyCursor(){
    var cursorCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.15,cursorsBought));
    if(cookies >= cursorCost){
      cursorsBought = cursorsBought + 1;
      cursors = cursors + 1;
        cookies = cookies - cursorCost;
      document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    }
    if(cursors >= nextCursorGoal) {
      cursorBonusMult = cursorBonusMult + 1;
      nextCursorGoal = Math.floor(nextCursorGoal * 2.5);
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(1.15,cursorsBought));
    document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
    document.getElementById('cursorCount').value = cursors;
    document.getElementById('cursorCount').max = nextCursorGoal;
    document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(cursorBonusMult) + " AutoClickers: " + preFix(cursors);
    document.getElementById('nextLVCursor').innerHTML = "Cursors needed for next level: " + preFix(nextCursorGoal);
};

var progs = 0;
var progsBought = 0;
var nextProgGoal = 10;
var progBonusMult = 1;

function buyProg(){
    var progCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.17,progsBought));
    if(cookies >= progCost){
      progsBought = progsBought + 1;
      progs = progs + 1;
        cookies = cookies - progCost;
      document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    };
    if(progs >= nextProgGoal) {
      progBonusMult = progBonusMult + 1;
      nextProgGoal = Math.floor(nextProgGoal * 2.5);
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(500 * Math.pow(1.17,progsBought));
    document.getElementById('progCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
    document.getElementById('progCount').value = progs;
    document.getElementById('progCount').max = nextProgGoal;
    document.getElementById('progs').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(progBonusMult) + " Programs: " + preFix(progs);
    document.getElementById('nextLVProg').innerHTML = "Programs needed for next level: " + preFix(nextProgGoal);
};

var advProgs = 0;
var advProgsBought = 0;
var nextAdvProgGoal = 10;
var advProgBonusMult = 1;

function buyAdvProg(){
    var advProgCost = Math.floor(7000 * Math.pow(1.13,advProgsBought));
    if(cookies >= advProgCost){
      advProgsBought = advProgsBought + 1;
      advProgs = advProgs + 1;
        cookies = cookies - advProgCost;
      document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    };
    if(advProgs >= nextAdvProgGoal) {
      advProgBonusMult = advProgBonusMult + 1;
      nextAdvProgGoal = Math.floor(nextAdvProgGoal * 2.5);
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(7000 * Math.pow(1.13,advProgsBought));
    document.getElementById('advProgCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
    document.getElementById('advProgCount').value = advProgs;
    document.getElementById('advProgCount').max = nextAdvProgGoal;
    document.getElementById('advProgs').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(advProgBonusMult) + " Adv. Programs: " + preFix(advProgs);
    document.getElementById('nextLVAdvProg').innerHTML = "Adv. Programs needed for next level: " + preFix(nextAdvProgGoal);
};

var clickerFoundry = 1;
var clickerFoundryBought = 0;
var nextFoundryGoal = 10;
var foundryBonusMult = 1;

function buyClickerFoundry(){
    var clickerFoundryCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.1,clickerFoundryBought));
    if(advProgs >= clickerFoundryCost){
      clickerFoundryBought = clickerFoundryBought + 1;
      clickerFoundry = clickerFoundry + 1;
        advProgs = advProgs - clickerFoundryCost;
      document.getElementById('advProgs').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(advProgBonusMult) + "Adv. Programs: " + preFix(advProgs);
      document.getElementById('advProgCount').value = advProgs;
      document.getElementById('advProgCount').max = nextAdvProgGoal;
    };
    if(clickerFoundry >= nextFoundryGoal) {
      foundryBonusMult = foundryBonusMult + 1;
      nextFoundryGoal = Math.floor(nextFoundryGoal * 2.5);
    };
    var nextCost = Math.floor(15 * Math.pow(1.1,clickerFoundryBought));
    document.getElementById('clickerFoundryCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Adv. Programs";
    document.getElementById('foundryCount').value = clickerFoundry;
    document.getElementById('foundryCount').max = nextFoundryGoal;
    document.getElementById('foundry').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(foundryBonusMult) + " Clicker Foundries: " + preFix(clickerFoundry);
    document.getElementById('nextLVFoundry').innerHTML = "Foundry needed for next level: " + preFix(nextFoundryGoal);
};

function createAutoClickers(number){
  cursors = cursors + number;
  if(cursors >= nextCursorGoal) {
    cursorBonusMult = cursorBonusMult + 1;
    nextCursorGoal = Math.floor(nextCursorGoal * 2.5);
  };
  document.getElementById('cursorCount').value = cursors;
  document.getElementById('cursorCount').max = nextCursorGoal;
  document.getElementById('cursors').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(cursorBonusMult) + " AutoClickers: " + preFix(cursors);
  document.getElementById('nextLVCursor').innerHTML = "Cursors needed for next level: " + preFix(nextCursorGoal);
};

var oldComputers = 0;
var oldComputersBought = 0;
var nextOldComputerGoal = 10;
var oldComputerBonusMult = 1;

function buyOldComputer(){
    var oldComputerCost = Math.floor(5 * Math.pow(1.1,oldComputersBought));
    if(clickerFoundry >= oldComputerCost){
      oldComputersBought = oldComputersBought + 1;
      oldComputers = oldComputers + 1;
        clickerFoundry = clickerFoundry - oldComputerCost;
      document.getElementById('foundry').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(foundryBonusMult) + " Clicker Foundries: " + preFix(clickerFoundry);
      document.getElementById('foundryCount').value = clickerFoundry;
      document.getElementById('foundryCount').max = nextFoundryGoal;
    };
    if(oldComputers >= nextOldComputerGoal) {
      oldComputerBonusMult = oldComputerBonusMult + 1;
      nextOldComputerGoal = Math.floor(nextOldComputerGoal * 2.5);
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(5 * Math.pow(1.1,oldComputersBought));
    document.getElementById('oldComputerCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Clicker Foundries";
    document.getElementById('oldComputerCount').value = oldComputers;
    document.getElementById('oldComputerCount').max = nextOldComputerGoal;
    document.getElementById('oldComputers').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(oldComputerBonusMult) + " Old Computers: " + preFix(oldComputers);
    document.getElementById('nextLVOldComp').innerHTML = "Old Computers needed for next level: " + preFix(nextOldComputerGoal);
};

function createProgs(number){
  progs = progs + number;
  if(progs >= nextProgGoal) {
    progBonusMult = progBonusMult + 1;
    nextProgGoal = Math.floor(nextProgGoal * 2.5);
  }
  document.getElementById('progCount').value = progs;
  document.getElementById('progCount').max = nextProgGoal;
  document.getElementById('progs').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(progBonusMult) + " Programs: " + preFix(progs);
  document.getElementById('nextLVProg').innerHTML = "Programs needed for next level: " + nextProgGoal;
};

var PCs = 0;
var PCsBought = 0;
var nextPCGoal = 10;
var PCBonusMult = 1;

function buyPC(){
    var PCCost = Math.floor(6 * Math.pow(1.1,PCsBought));
    if(oldComputers >= PCCost){
      PCsBought = PCsBought + 1;
      PCs = PCs + 1;
        oldComputers = oldComputers - PCCost;
      document.getElementById('oldComputers').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(oldComputerBonusMult) + " Old Computers: " + preFix(oldComputers);
      document.getElementById('oldComputerCount').value = oldComputers;
      document.getElementById('oldComputerCount').max = nextOldComputerGoal;
    };
    if(oPCs >= nextPCGoal) {
      PCBonusMult++;
      nextOPCGoal = Math.floor(nextPCGoal * 2.5);
    }
    var nextCost = Math.floor(6 * Math.pow(1.1,PCsBought));
    document.getElementById('PCCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Old Computers";
    document.getElementById('PCCount').value = PCs;
    document.getElementById('PCCount').max = nextPCGoal;
    document.getElementById('PCs').innerHTML = "Lv." + preFix(PCBonusMult) + " PCs: " + preFix(PCs);
    document.getElementById('nextLVPC').innerHTML = "PCs needed for next level: " + preFix(nextPCGoal);
};

var manualMultBought = 0;

function buyManualMult(){
    var manualMultCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(8.7,manualMultBought));
    if(cookies >= manualMultCost){
      manualMultBought = manualMultBought + 1;
      manualMult = manualMult * 2;
        cookies = cookies - manualMultCost;
    };
    document.getElementById('manualMult').innerHTML = "Button Multiplyer: " + preFix(manualMult) + "x";
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    var nextCost = Math.floor(50 * Math.pow(8.7,manualMultBought));
    document.getElementById('manualMultCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
};

var clickMultBought = 0;

function buyClickMult(){
    var clickMultCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(6.35,clickMultBought));
    if(cookies >= clickMultCost){
      clickMultBought = clickMultBought + 1;
      clickMult = clickMult + 1;
        cookies = cookies - clickMultCost;
    };
    document.getElementById('clickMult').innerHTML = "Click Multiplyer: " + preFix(clickMult) + "x";
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    var nextCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(6.35,clickMultBought));
    document.getElementById('clickMultCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
};

var progMultBought = 0;

function buyProgMult(){
    var progMultCost = Math.floor(66500 * Math.pow(9.65,progMultBought));
    if(cookies >= progMultCost){
      progMultBought = progMultBought + 1;
      progMult = progMult + 1;
        cookies = cookies - progMultCost;
    };
    document.getElementById('progMult').innerHTML = "Program Multiplyer: " + preFix(progMult) + "x";
    document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";
    var nextCost = Math.floor(66500 * Math.pow(9.65,progMultBought));
    document.getElementById('progMultCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
};



//Tick related

var gameTick = 50;
var cursorTick = 0;
var progTick = 0;
var advProgTick = 0;
var foundryTick = 0;
var oldCompTick = 0;
var PCTick = 0;
var cursorTickAct = 40;
var progTickAct = 20;
var advProgTickAct = 20;
var foundryTickAct = 400;
var oldCompTickAct = 180;
var PCTickAct = 150;

var cursorSpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyCursorSpeedUpgrade(){

  var cursorSpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(1050 * Math.pow(3.5,cursorSpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= cursorSpeedUpgradeCost && cursorSpeedUpgrades < 72){
    cursorSpeedUpgrades = cursorSpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - cursorSpeedUpgradeCost;
    cursorTickAct = cursorTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('CursorSpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "AutoClicker Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(cursorSpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(cursorSpeedUpgrades < 72) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(1050 * Math.pow(3.5,cursorSpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('CursorSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(cursorSpeedUpgrades >= 72) {
    document.getElementById('CursorSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

var progSpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyProgSpeedUpgrade(){

  var progSpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(73000 * Math.pow(4.4,progSpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= progSpeedUpgradeCost && progSpeedUpgrades < 59){
    progSpeedUpgrades = progSpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - progSpeedUpgradeCost;
    progTickAct = progTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('ProgSpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "Program Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(progSpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(progSpeedUpgrades < 59) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(73000 * Math.pow(4.4,progSpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('ProgSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(progSpeedUpgrades >= 59) {
    document.getElementById('ProgSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

var advProgSpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyAdvProgSpeedUpgrade(){

  var advProgSpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(509000 * Math.pow(5.1,advProgSpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= advProgSpeedUpgradeCost && advProgSpeedUpgrades < 59){
    advProgSpeedUpgrades = advProgSpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - advProgSpeedUpgradeCost;
    advProgTickAct = advProgTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('AdvProgSpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "Adv. Program Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(advProgSpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(advProgSpeedUpgrades < 59) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(509000 * Math.pow(5.1,advProgSpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('AdvProgSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(advProgSpeedUpgrades >= 59) {
    document.getElementById('AdvProgSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

var foundrySpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyFoundrySpeedUpgrade(){

  var foundrySpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(3050000 * Math.pow(2.7,foundrySpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= foundrySpeedUpgradeCost && foundrySpeedUpgrades < 117){
    foundrySpeedUpgrades = foundrySpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - foundrySpeedUpgradeCost;
    foundryTickAct = foundryTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('FoundrySpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "Clicker Foundry Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(foundrySpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(foundrySpeedUpgrades < 117) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(3050000 * Math.pow(2.7,foundrySpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('FoundrySpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(foundrySpeedUpgrades >= 117) {
    document.getElementById('FoundrySpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

var oldCompSpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyOldCompSpeedUpgrade(){

  var oldCompSpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(205000000 * Math.pow(2.9,oldCompSpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= oldCompSpeedUpgradeCost && oldCompSpeedUpgrades < 102){
    oldCompSpeedUpgrades = oldCompSpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - oldCompSpeedUpgradeCost;
    oldCompTickAct = oldCompTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('OldCompSpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "Old Computer Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(oldCompSpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(oldCompSpeedUpgrades < 102) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(205000000 * Math.pow(2.9,oldCompSpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('OldCompSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(oldCompSpeedUpgrades >= 102) {
    document.getElementById('OldCompSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

var PCSpeedUpgrades = 0;

function buyPCSpeedUpgrade(){

  var PCSpeedUpgradeCost = Math.floor(71000000000 * Math.pow(3.4,PCSpeedUpgrades));

  if(cookies >= PCSpeedUpgradeCost && PCSpeedUpgrades < 98){
    PCSpeedUpgrades = PCSpeedUpgrades + 1;
    cookies = cookies - PCSpeedUpgradeCost;
    PCTickAct = PCTickAct * 0.95;
  };
  document.getElementById('PCSpeedUpgrades').innerHTML = "PC Speed Upgrades: " + preFix(PCSpeedUpgrades);
  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";

  if(PCSpeedUpgrades < 98) {
    var nextCost = Math.floor(71000000000 * Math.pow(3.4,PCSpeedUpgrades));
    document.getElementById('PCSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(nextCost) + " Bits";
  };

  if(PCSpeedUpgrades >= 98) {
    document.getElementById('PCSpeedUpgradeCost').innerHTML = "Maxed";
  };

};

window.setInterval(function(){

  document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(noDec(cookies)) + " Bits";

  accentionPointsGained = Math.floor((clicks/1e12) + ((cursorsBought + progsBought + advProgsBought + clickerFoundryBought + oldComputersBought + PCsBought)/1000) + (((cursors - cursorsBought) + (progs - progsBought) + (advProgs - advProgsBought) + (clickerFoundry - clickerFoundryBought) + (oldComputers - oldComputersBought) + (PCs - PCsBought))/10000) + (cookies/1e12));

  cursorTick++;
  document.getElementById('cursorCost').innerHTML = "Cost: " + preFix(buyCursor.cursorCost) + " Bits";
  document.getElementById('cursorCount').value = cursors;
  if(cursorTick >= cursorTickAct) {
    buttonClick(Math.floor(cursors * clickMult * cursorBonusMult * accentionMult));
    cursorTick = 0;
  };

  progTick++;
  if(progTick >= progTickAct) {
    buttonClick(Math.floor(7 * progs * progMult * progBonusMult * accentionMult));
    progTick = 0;
  }

  advProgTick++;
  if(advProgTick >= advProgTickAct) {
    buttonClick(Math.floor(59 * advProgs * progMult * advProgBonusMult * accentionMult));
    advProgTick = 0;
  }

  foundryTick++;
  if(foundryTick >= foundryTickAct) {
    createAutoClickers(Math.floor(clickerFoundry * foundryBonusMult * accentionMult));
    foundryTick = 0;
  }

  oldCompTick++;
  if(oldCompTick >= oldCompTickAct) {
    createProgs(Math.floor(oldComputers * oldComputerBonusMult * accentionMult));
    oldCompTick = 0;
  };

  PCTick++;
  if(PCTick >= PCTickAct) {
    createProgs(Math.floor(7 * PCs * PCBonusMult * accentionMult));
    PCTick = 0;
  };

  if(accentionPointsGained >= 1){
    document.getElementById('canAccendText').innerHTML = "Press to Accend";
    document.getElementById('accentionPointsGainedText').innerHTML = "Matrix Points gained on Accention: ";
    document.getElementById('accentionPointsGained').innerHTML = preFix(accentionPointsGained) + " Matrix Points";
  };

}, gameTick);



//Accention related

var accendCursors = 0;

function buyAccendCursor(number){
  var accendCursorCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(10,accendCursors));
  if(accentionPoints >= accendCursorCost) {
    accendCursors = accendCursors + 1;
    accentionPoints = accentionPoints - accendCursorCost;
  };


};

function askToAccend(){

  if(accentionPointsGained >= 1){
    accend();
  };

}

function accend(){

  document.getElementById('canAccendText').innerHTML = "Accention locked";
  document.getElementById('accentionPointsGainedText').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('accentionPointsGained').innerHTML = "";

  accentions++;
  accentionMult = accentionMult * BetterRound5(Math.pow(1.001,accentionPointsGained) * Math.pow(1.0005,accentions));
  accentionPoints = accentionPoints + accentionPointsGained;
  accentionPointsGained = 0;
  document.getElementById('accentionMult').innerHTML = "Accention Multiplyer: " + preFix(BetterRound5(accentionMult)) + "x";

  document.getElementById('accentionStuff1').innerHTML = "Matrix Points: ";
  document.getElementById('accentionPoints').innerHTML = preFix(accentionPoints);

  //document.getElementById('accentionStuff2')

  cookies = 0;
  manualMult = 1;
  clickMult = 1;
  progMult = 1;

  clicks = 0;
  nextClickGoal = 5000;
  clickBonusMult = 1;

  cursors = accendCursors;
  cursorsBought = 0;
  nextCursorGoal = 10;
  cursorBonusMult = 1;

  progs = 0;
  progsBought = 0;
  nextProgGoal = 10;
  progBonusMult = 1;

  advProgs = 0;
  advProgsBought = 0;
  nextAdvProgGoal = 10;
  advProgBonusMult = 1;

  clickerFoundry = 0;
  clickerFoundryBought = 0;
  nextFoundryGoal = 10;
  foundryBonusMult = 1;

  oldComputers = 0;
  oldComputersBought = 0;
  nextOldComputerGoal = 10;
  oldComputerBonusMult = 1;

  PCs = 0;
  PCsBought = 0;
  nextPCGoal = 10;
  PCBonusMult = 1;

  manualMultBought = 0;

  clickMultBought = 0;

  progMultBought = 0;

  gameTick = 50;
  cursorTick = 0;
  progTick = 0;
  advProgTick = 0;
  foundryTick = 0;
  oldCompTick = 0;
  PCTick = 0;
  cursorTickAct = 40;
  progTickAct = 20;
  advProgTickAct = 20;
  foundryTickAct = 400;
  oldCompTickAct = 180;
  PCTickAct = 150;

  cursorSpeedUpgrades = 0;

  progSpeedUpgrades = 0;

  advProgSpeedUpgrades = 0;

  foundrySpeedUpgrades = 0;

  oldCompSpeedUpgrades = 0;

  PCSpeedUpgrades = 0;

};
```

Comment: Add only relevant code. never ever dump your whole code. Its not useful. Narrow down your problem

Comment: The code snippet you posted does not contain "myFunction"...

Comment: @Satpal that is the shortened version, I already removed a lot of unnecessary  code.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak "myFunction" is the standard replacement for functions, similar as x is usually used for variables. I used "myFunction" as it wasen't a specific function that didn't work, but it returned the same thing for all functions.

Comment: Renaming your functions or rewriting the error outputs is not helpful while searching for a bug.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 422: you have a `¨` that's not supposed to be there:

```
document.getElementById('cookies').innerHTML = preFix(cookies) + " Bits";¨
```

Your browser chokes on that `¨` and won't interpret any code after that.

EDIT: Also, at line 610:

```
oldComputerBonusMult = 1;´
```

Remove that `´`.

Comment: While I'm thankful for finding that, it doesn't really help. I did however fix that.

Comment: Ah, yes, I noticed that too after you mentioned it.

Comment: I've been going through my thing some times now add I've got everything working. Seems that you were correct, and that I've been looking for the wrong things.